# What to do instinctively when someone tries multiple vulnerable urls

Tags: security

I have a Symfony site running on production. Since two weeks I noticed in the logs these attempts:

- GET /nmaplowercheck1557094092
- GET /evox/about
- GET /HNAP1
- POST /sdk
- GET /.env
- GET /admin//config.php
- GET /console/login/LoginForm.jsp

I'm neither a sysadmin nor a devops. I don't know how to react. Does it sound like a warning to you ? Meaning that I should focus on the security of my server ? Should I take preventive measures ?

I found this github: https://github.com/imthenachoman/How-To-Secure-A-Linux-Server but I didn't start anything.

What's your opinion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get all kinds of garbage requests on the Internet, trying to identify what your service is and maybe trying vulnerabilities.

If you don't know what to do, hire someone who does. Maybe for a one time engagement to check this app and give you advice. Ideally they have experience in this particular platform, and maybe penetration testing web apps in general.

Building protection yourself requires developing a few skills.

As sysadmin, apply security updates. Watch audit logs and such for suspicious behavior. And be ready with the business continuity plan if you have to blow away everything and restore from backup.

As security person, read up on protecting web apps, for example over on Security.SE: [How can I defend against malicious GET requests?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95119/how-can-i-defend-against-malicious-get-requests)  OWSAP publishes good resources on web app security. Be aware of the classes of threats, such as cross-site scripting and SQL injection. There's a whole class of security products in this space, usually called web application firewalls.

Always more you can do, and not everything is a high severity threat. But take the opportunity to get educated and put more defenses in place.

Comment: Thanks John I'll try to level up my security related skills